# Why can I update a DataGrid itemsource without neither using an Observable Collection, nor calling Items.Refresh()?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

The title is correct. I'd like to know why this *is* working:

I have a datagrid with its ItemsSource bound to a property of type `List<object>`. On the code behind, I instantiate a new `List<object>`, fill it using a loop, and raise my `PropertyChanged` event. This results in the datagrid being updated. However, I was under the impression that I should use an `ObservableCollection<object>` rather than a `List<object>` otherwise the data grid wouldn't update... Yet it did.

Here's the relevant code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgv_Items"
         Grid.Row="3"
         Grid.ColumnSpan="19"
         Grid.RowSpan="4"
         ItemsSource="{Binding ITEMS}"
         FontWeight="Bold"
         GridLinesVisibility="None"
         IsReadOnly="True"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemI, Mode=TwoWay}"
         SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow">
  <DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Param, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="Conferido">
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Param, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="Achado">
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Orange"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Param, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="Inexistente">
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

```cs
public List<ItemImportado> ITEMS { get; set; }

public async Task<bool> ImportaNFE(string path)
{
    ITEMS = new List<ItemImportado>();
    foreach (var det in TNFE.infNFe.det)
    {
        ITEMS.Add(new ItemImportado()
        {
            CodFornec = det.prod.cProd,
            DescFornec = det.prod.xProd,
            Quant = decimal.Parse(det.prod.qCom, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
            VlrUnit = decimal.Parse(det.prod.vUnCom, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
            NItem = int.Parse(det.nItem),
            Detalhamento = det
        });

    }
    OnPropertyChanged(null);
}
```

The `DataGrid` doesn't have an explicit `UpdateSourceTrigger`, and I didn't call `dgv.Items.Refresh()`. How come it updates the data grid's items? Does the style binding updates the data grid's items as well?

Comment: You raised property changed, and binding reevaluated your list, all seems as expected. After all that is why you raise property changed for properies bound to your UI.

Comment: So when using ObservableCollection, I wouldn't need to call PropertyChanged?

Comment: No, it has it's own events which are raised when you modify it. With current approach - whole list is reevaluated. With ObservableCollection - if you added one item there for example, then only this item is handled (UI element is created for it and so on)

Comment: But if you never add or remove items from your collection, and always just replace it as a whole - your current approach is correct and you don't need ObservableCollection. And if you do use ObservableCollection and want to replace it - you need to raise property changed (because indeed property has changed). Only when you modify collection itself with Add/Remove etc - you don't need to do anything

Comment: Also note that UpdateSourceTrigger has nothing to do with all of this. It only controls how the source property of a binding is updated when the target property changes. It only has an effect on TwoWay or OneWayToSource Bindings.

Comment: And `OnPropertyChanged(null)` should be `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ITEMS))`

Comment: @Clemens The class has a bunch more properties that are updated when that method is called. By using null as the parameter, `OnPropertyChanged` tells the UI **every** property has changed

Comment: @Evk It makes sense! I always used both ObservableCollection _and_ OnPropertyChanged... So, if I had like a datagrid with a bunch of entries that are subject to change, I would need an ObservableCollection and a backend method to update it only, and the UI would automatically update the new/edited entries? That right?

Comment: I know that, but there is no indication in your question that you also knew it. And in the context of the question it does not make sense. Also be aware that it is good practice to use ObservableCollections as read-only properties. You would not need to fire the PropertyChanged event. Just create a collection once and if necessary only clear it before adding new items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UI is updated because you fire the PropertyChanged event after assigning a new value to the collection property and adding items to it.

---

Instead of creating a new collection instance each time, you may better use a readonly ObservableCollection property:

```
public ObservableCollection<ItemImportado> Items { get; }
    = new ObservableCollection<ItemImportado>();

public void ImportaNFE()
{
    Items.Clear();

    foreach (var det in TNFE.infNFe.det)
    {
        Items.Add(new ItemImportado
        {
            ...
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I use ObservableCollections with EF Core models?

Comment: Sure, why not ?

Comment: I was taught when creating foreign one-to-many EF relations I was supposed to use List<object> only. I'll change the lists to observablecollections then. Thank you so much!!